# Deleting duplicates from same SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, subquery, sql-delete

My table looks like this (in SQL Server 2016 SP2):

```
KEY | CN_ID | CNO_IND
----+-------+--------
001 | P001  | N
002 | P001  | Y
003 | P001  | N
005 | P002  | N
006 | P002  | N
007 | P004  | N
008 | P004  | Y
009 | P004  | N
010 | P004  | Y
```

Here's what I want to do:

For all CN_ID with CNO_IND = 'Y', I want to delete all the CN_ID with CNO_IND = 'N'.

My final result will be like this:

```
KEY | CN_ID | CNO_IND
----+-------+--------
002 | P001  | Y
005 | P002  | N
006 | P002  | N
008 | P004  | Y
010 | P004  | Y
```

As you can see, P002 will not be deleted since none of P002 has CNO_IND = 'Y'. P004 still has duplicates since I want to retain all records with CNO_IND = 'Y' and remove duplicates with CNO_IND = 'N'.

Hope to find the best solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

One option uses `exists`:

```
delete t
from mytable t
where cno_ind = 'N' and exists (
    select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.cn_id = t.cn_id and t1.cno_ind = 'Y'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE Something like this

```
With CTE as (
Select KEY, CN_ID, CNO_IND, Row_Number() over (Partition by CN_ID  Order By CN_ID) as rnk from YourTable
)

Delete from CTE where rnk > 1
```

Comment: this will delete records with CNO_IND = 'Y' which I want to retain and also one of the P002.

Comment: This answer is not correct.  I'm surprised it is upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

But you still can do it with CTE:

```
With del as (
  Select
    [KEY], CN_ID, CNO_IND,
    max(case CNO_IND when 'Y' then 'Y' end) over (Partition by CN_ID) as has_y
  from tab
)

delete
from del
where has_y = 'Y'
  and cno_ind = 'N'
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=ff79dcfb70682ae5603efcad19aac864)

In your example result you've left duplicates for `P002` which has only N despite your need to delete duplicated N's, so I didn't delete duplicates of N with only N too.

Comment: yes, if a CN_ID  has no Y , I want to retain them. Once it has a Y, delete the duplicates with N only.

Comment: I think this works, but I am getting a warning message.

Comment: @AzLateef DBMS just informs you how it works, but if you know SQL you'll know that aggregate functions ignore nulls. You can just test it in the fiddle I've provided, no need to guess is it working statement or not.